# MariaDB - supply DER formatted CA with serverSslCert

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tls1.2, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am building a MariaDB connection string where according to the following documentation I would like to supply the CA certificate directly in the string rather than a file:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j

> serverSslCert -  Permits providing server's certificate in DER form,
> or server's CA certificate. The server will be added to trustStor.
> This permits a self-signed certificate to be trusted. Can be used in
> one of 3 forms :
>
> - serverSslCert=/path/to/cert.pem (full path to certificate)
> - serverSslCert=classpath:relative/cert.pem (relative to current classpath)
> - or as verbatim DER-encoded certificate string "------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" . since 1.1.3

With the last point - do we have an example of providing inline CA in DER format?
I am trying to connect to MySQL RDS in AWS and providing below pem file works:
https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem

```
jdbc:mysql://my-host:3306/dbname?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true&autoReconnect=true&permitMysqlScheme&serverSslCert=/tmp/global-bundle.pem
```

How can I supply this file inline with DER in the connection string?

PS: I am using Spring Cloud Data Flow Server where you will have to use MariaDB connector to talk to MySQL hence I need to build the URL with MariaDB parameters with `mysql` as a scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you **could** just add the full string from the file into the connection url param:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-host:3306/dbname?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=true&autoReconnect=true&permitMysqlScheme&serverSslCert=<YOUR_SUPER_LONG_DER_STRING>
```

Have you tried this approach? Even if it does work, I would not paste my key directly in a config file. Besides leading to a gigantic url in a config file, your key would be visible.

It could instead be inserted as an env var that is populated by your runtime. If you are running in Kubernetes this could be a secret that feeds the env var.

I think this 3rd option of setting the key in the url param may have been intended to use when building the URL programmatically.